# PHP scandir filenames with Turkish characters

Tags: php, string, filenames

I am listing documents with PHP scandir. I have problem with some characters like ğ, ı, ş...
So this is my code;

```
$directory = "document";
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory, 1), array('..', '.'));
foreach ($scanned_directory as &$value) {
    echo utf8_encode($value);
}
```

Actually the filename is "şığx.jpg" but the output is "þýðx.jpg". utf8_encode did not solved this. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8. ISO-8859-1 does not have turkish characters.

Comment: FoX: I saw that post before posting here. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_encode` will not help you here, as your filesystem is likely in different encoding. Use

```
echo iconv($in_charset, 'UTF-8', $value);
```

where `$in_charset` might be `ISO-8859-9`, `windows-1254`, or `CP857`.

Or if you haven't tried, maybe your filesystem is in utf already ;).