# PHP - Get all files in a folders with foreign characters

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to read all the files in a directory with umlaut characters using PHP?

For example, in our Directory, we have a file named "Köln.pdf". When we use scandir method, it returns 'K"ln.pdf'.

Is there a way to retrieve the file names with those character? 
We are using PHP7.2 in Azure App Service.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Maybe [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660797/php-scandir-and-htmlentities-issues-with-charset-and-or-special-characters) helps?

Comment: @Grabatui, scandir method itself is not returning those characters. So, not sure if it works even if we pass the file names to those other methods

Comment: Worth a read https://stackoverflow.com/a/26677515/2310830

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1525830/2943403

Comment: @Prawin Were you able to get through this?